# Why isn't this program compiling

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
class Abc // created class with name Abc
{
    void display()//member function
    {
        cout<<"Displaying NO."<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Abc obj;//creating object of the class
    obj.display();//calling member function inside class
}
```

It returns error as

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:10: error: 'void Abc::display()' is private
     void display()
          ^
main.cpp:13:17: error: within this context
     obj.display();
                 ^
```

I have tried to make display function `public int main` but then it gives error as

```
main.cpp:5:11: error: expected ':' before 'void'
    public void display()
           ^
```

Comment: The error message is *very* descriptive. Default access specifier in `class` is `private`.

Comment: Read the books thoroughly, don't just take and glance and start programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear enough. You may not call a private member function outside the class. By default classes with keyword class have private access control by default. Either write

```
class Abc // created class with name Abc
{
public:
 void display()//member function
    {
        cout<<"Displaying NO."<<endl;
    }
};
```

or

```
struct Abc // created class with name Abc
{
 void display()//member function
    {
        cout<<"Displaying NO."<<endl;
    }
};
```

Classes with keyword struct have public access control  by default.

Also it would be better to define the member function as

```
 void display() const//member function
 {
        std::cout<<"Displaying NO."<<endl;
 }
```

Take into account that as you did not use directibe

```
using namespace std;
```

you have to use qualified names with entities declared in std::. For example

```
        std::cout<<"Displaying NO."<<std::endl;
```

Comment: can you tell me what's the use of below line:
using namespace std;

Comment: `endl` is also part of `std`

Comment: @vivek321 All names declared in header <iostream> belong to the namespace std::. The directive says the compiler that if it meet such a name as cout it have to look also through the names declared in this header.

Answer (score 5):

Declare it as:

```
class Abc
{
public:

    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Displaying NO."<<endl;
    }
};
```

or:

```
struct Abc
{
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Displaying NO."<<endl;
    }
};
```

**struct**'s default protection is public, **class**'s default protection is private

Comment: Or change `Abc` to `struct` ;)